# R Shiny click on table field

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently learning R. I have a small project where a timetable is displayed and the user has the option to enter a subject.

After adding the subject to the timetable, it should be possible to click on it to open the modalDialog.
Unfortunately my code does not work. I have tried it here:

```
observeEvent(input$mytable_cells_selected, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Somewhat important message",
      "This is a somewhat important message.",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL))
  })
```

Can someone help me and tell where my error is?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
      titlePanel(h1("My timetable", align = "center" )),
      sidebarLayout(
        position = c("left"),
        sidebarPanel(
          width = 4,
          selectInput("select1", label = h5("Event:"),
                      choices = c("math" , "sience", "sport") ,
                      selected = 1,
                      width = 400),
          actionButton("action", label = "Add")),
        mainPanel(
          width = 8,
          tableOutput('mytable')),
      ),
    )
```

and server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  timetable <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(monday = c("","","","",""),
               tuesday = c("","","","",""),
               wednesday = c("","","","",""),
               thursday = c("","","","",""),
               friday = c("","","","",""))
  )
   
  output$mytable <- renderTable(timetable(), 
          bordered = TRUE, 
          spacing = c('l'), 
          width = "100%",
          striped = TRUE,
          align = 'c',
          rownames = TRUE,
          selection = list(target = 'cell'))
  
  observeEvent(input$action, { 
    tmp <- timetable()
    tmp[1, "monday"] <- input$select1
    timetable(tmp)
  })

  observeEvent(input$mytable_cells_selected, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
         title = "message",
         "This is a somewhat important message.",
         easyClose = TRUE,
         footer = NULL))
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `library(DT)` has good integration with shiny (have a look at functions `DTOutput()`and `renderDT()`) and provides many actions and features, like click or edit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried to work with it and revised the code, but unfortunately it does not work. I can not find the error ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use the `DT` library. Here is a complete example.

Use `dataTableOutput` in your `ui` for your data table.

In `server`, you can include `renderDataTable` and customize here. In this case, selection is set for single cells.

You can capture the selection event (or can capture clicked event) with `input$my_table_cells_selected`. In my version I used an underscore for `my_table`. This information will include the row and column values of the cell selected.

Note that the `DT` data table could be editable and allow for other interactivity, depending on your needs.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
  titlePanel(h1("My timetable", align = "center" )),
  sidebarLayout(
    position = c("left"),
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 4,
      selectInput("select1", label = h5("Event:"),
                  choices = c("math" , "sience", "sport") ,
                  selected = 1,
                  width = 400),
      actionButton("action", label = "Add")),
    mainPanel(
      width = 8,
      dataTableOutput('my_table')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  timetable <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(monday = c("","","","",""),
               tuesday = c("","","","",""),
               wednesday = c("","","","",""),
               thursday = c("","","","",""),
               friday = c("","","","",""))
  )
   
  output$my_table = renderDataTable(timetable(), selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell"))
  
  observeEvent(input$action, { 
    tmp <- timetable()
    tmp[1, "monday"] <- input$select1
    timetable(tmp)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$my_table_cells_selected, {
    req(input$my_table_cells_selected)
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "message",
      paste("This is a somewhat important message:", 
            input$my_table_cells_selected[1],
            input$my_table_cells_selected[2]),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks again! Now I understand it. I was not aware of the difference between rendertable and renderdatatable. 
The underscore also helped me a lot. Project is now successfully completed because of your help. :)